# Fill in space between elements when using border-radius

Tags: css

When I create a grid using a large enough border-radius property on the grid cells and a gap property, gaps appear at the corners inbetween the elements (the red background).

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,calc(90vw/3));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3,calc(90vh/3));
  gap: 1vmin;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
}
.cell {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1vmin solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How would I go about filling these gaps with the same color as my border?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a gradient coloration:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  background: linear-gradient(black 0 0) 50%/90% 90% no-repeat;
  gap: 1vmin;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
}

.cell {
  background-color: gray;
  outline: 1vmin solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This option is also good, If you want to keep it in the middle of the boxes

Answer (score 2):

You can set `background-color` of the container to achieve this.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,calc(90vw/3));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3,calc(90vh/3));
  background-color: black;
  gap: 1vmin;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
}
.cell {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1vmin solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good solution, but is there a way to make it so the container only covers the inner corners and not the outer corners? similar to how it looks on the bottom elements right now

Answer (score 1):

**If you change the css, then the design can be a little better.**

```css
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
        .grid {
        background-color: black;
     display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    
    border-radius: 16px;
}
.cell {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    max-width: 33.333333%;
      height:70px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="grid">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```